# How to allow removal of USB-drive with LUKS key while keeping device decrypted untill reboot or logout?

Tags: luks

I'm running DietPi (Debian) on a raspberry pi where I've mounted an external drive encrypted with LUKS. I use a USB drive to decrypt the LUKS device at boot/login using:

a `/etc/crypttab` as such:

```
<mapper name> UUID=<uuid of luks-part> /mnt/key-usb/my_keyfile
```

a `/etc/cryptdisks` like so:

```
CRYPTDISK_MOUNT='/mnt/key-usb'
```

and finally a `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
...
UUID=<mapper\decrypted device> /mnt/decrypted auto defaults,rw,noatime,nofail, x-systemd.automount 0 0
UUID=<uuid of key USB> /mnt/key-usb auto auto defaults,rw,noatime,nofail, x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=5 0 0
...
```

This unlocks/decrypts the LUKS partition on boot and I can access my files. But if I remove the usb mounted to `/mnt/key-usb` I cannot access the files anymore. Is there a way to keep the device unlocked without the USB present until the user logs off or reboots the machine?

I've seen some setups where a fourth column is added to the `etc/crypttab` such as `keyscript=devpass|decrypt_keyctl`, I tried that but it did nothing. It seems this script should be located in `/lib/cryptdisks/scripts/` but on my machine these seem to be located in `/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/`. How would one (could one?) make this possible with a custom script?